# Zwiebelschmalz auf Englisch

Tags: translation, single-word-request, german-to-english

Ich versuche grade, *Zwiebelschmalz*[1] ins Englische zu übersetzen. Ich habe es mit "onion lard" versucht, was ein ziemlich erfolgloser Versuch war, da sich *lard* normalerweise auf Schweinefett bezieht und eine eher unappetitliche Konnotation hat. Jetzt weiss ich nicht weiter. Gibt es ueberhaupt das kulinarische Produkt Zwiebelschmalz im Englischen?

[1] Zwiebelschmalz ist eine Art Creme, bestehend aus Zwiebel und Pflanzenöl, evtl. mit Kräutern angereichert. Oft wird Zwiebelschmalz als Brotaufstrich verwendet: in dieser Form ähnelt er Erdnussbutter im Aussehen und in der Textur. (Lecker!)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the German language.

Comment: Arguably; I think that translating from one language to the other is symmetric in the extent to which it involves both languages. Yes, we are translating into English, but we are *considering* and *thinking about* the German expression.

Comment: Was ist unappetitlich an "Lard"? "Culinary use: Many chefs and bakers deem lard a superior cooking fat over other types of shortening" [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lard)

Comment: Zwiebelschmalz aus Pflanzenöl ist mir aus dem Alltag nicht bekannt, insofern würde _lard_ passen; siehe auch http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmalz#Zwiebelschmalz.2FApfelschmalz.

Comment: @Newb Vor 9h kannte ich den Begriff "Zwiebelschmalz" noch gar nicht, und nur dank Deiner Erklärung konnte ich meine Antwort finden. Was hier _in Frage_ stand, war also ganz klar der englische Begriff dafür. Solche Fragen sind hier off-topic, soweit ich weiß. Siehe z.B. [hier](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/136/are-translation-requests-from-german-allowed-sind-fragen-nach-%C3%9Cbersetzungen). Persönlich wäre ich aber dafür, diese Einschränkung aufzuheben. Mir scheint auch, es gibt keinen klaren Konsens dazu. Sollten wir die Frage nochmal nach German Meta tragen?

Comment: [Translations requests from German should be restricted to cases where a profound knowledge of German is needed for understanding a phrase or an idiom.](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and related Meta Post: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/136/are-translation-requests-from-german-allowed-sind-fragen-nach-%c3%9cbersetzungen

Comment: Man könnte sagen "Zwiebelschmalz" bräuchte eine tiefe Kenntnis deutscher Essgewohnheiten... aber m.E. sind die Unterschiede im anglo-amerikanischen Raum nicht wirklich vorhanden.

Comment: English seems to distinguish between "lard" (mainly from pork) and Schmaltz (from poultry). As for the onions I think "with onions" is the most widespread (no pun intended)  44.100 hits on google for "Lard with onions"

Comment: Zu behaupten, dass Zwiebelschmalz eine Creme aus Pflanzenöl sei, ist genau so korrekt wie die Behauptung, dass Wurst, Schnitzel und Steaks aus Tofu gemacht werden.

Comment: @jarnbjo Klar, genauso wie Erdnußbutter aus Butter gemacht wird, Malzkaffee Kaffeebohnen enthält, Reismilch Milch, Pfefferminztee Tee- und Coca-Cola Kokablätter,  vom Marzipanbrot ganz zu schweigen - genauso muß natürlich Zwiebelschmalz aus Schmalz gemacht werden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wie wäre es mit *onion cream*?

[Hier ist ein Rezept für "Onion Cream"](http://www.healthy.net/Recipe/Health/Onion_Cream/78), das sich für mich sehr nach Deiner Beschreibung anhört.

Abgesehen davon glaube ich, daß die Frage leider tatsächlich off-topic ist.

Comment: What am I missing, why is it off-topic?

Comment: @Grantwalzer Siehe meinen Kommentar zur Frage.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Dein Deutsch kann so gut sein wie es will - es hilft Dir nicht die Frage zu beantworten. Du musst einen guten englischen Wortschatz haben, um die Antwort geben zu können. Wenn Du Dt. u. Französisch super kannst, und den Begriff ins Französische übersetzen kannst, bist Du immer noch nicht weiter. Du musst auch das dt. Wort nicht kennen, um die Frage zu stellen - ein Video oder eine englische Umschreibung täte es auch.

Comment: @userunknown Ohh, now I see...

Answer (score 0):

Schmalz ([Lard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lard)) ist auch im englischsprachigen Raum ein weitverbreitetes Nahrungsmittel.

> Many chefs and bakers deem lard a superior cooking fat over other types of shortening because of lard's range of applications and taste.<sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lard)</sup>

Es ist in vielen Teilen der Welt auch als Brotaufstrich (*spread*) bekannt, auch in Kombination mit Grieben oder gerösteten Zwiebeln. Allerdings hat Zwiebelschmalz wohl in Deutschland und Österreich die meiste Verbreitung.

Mein Vorschlag einer hinreichend verständlichen Übersetzung des Brotaufstrichs "Zwiebelschmalz" wäre:

> Onion flavo(u)red lard spread

Comment: Ungefähr so hätte ich _Zwiebelschmalz_ übersetzt, wenn da nicht die genauere Beschreibung in der Frage wäre. _Lard_ scheint ausschließlich Schweinefett zu bezeichnen. Das würde nicht zur Vorgabe "Pflanzenöl" passen, und auch _Gänseschmalz_ ließe sich nicht nach diesem Muster übersetzen.

Comment: @Matthias ...es gäbe da noch den englischen Begriff *Schmaltz*, der aber vermutlich nicht so bekannt ist. *Tallow* (Talg) würde ich nicht nehmen, das hat glaube ich eher den erwähnten unappetitlichen Beigeschmack (*pun intended*). Man könnte dezidiert *goose lard* sagen, wenn man Gänseschmalz meint. Auch bei uns ist Schmalz, wenn nicht anders erwähnt, meist Schweineschmalz, und eben nicht eine Pflanzenölcreme. Das Rezept in der Frage ist m.E. irreführend.

Comment: So etwa könnte die Frage zum Beispiel *on topic* gestaltet werden: Ist "Schmalz" immer Tierfett, oder kann man auch zu Pflanzenölzubereitungen "Schmalz" sagen? Ist *"Schmalz" ohne Zusatz immer "Schweineschmalz"?

Comment: Hm, wäre es dann nicht eher eine Frage für cooking.se? Aber die sind vermutlich "English only" :-( --- [Schmaltz](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schmaltz) ist im Englischen wohl ausschließlich die Übersetzung für die metaphorische Bedeutung des deutschen Begriffes.

Comment: Irreführend würde ich das Rezept nicht nennen: der Begriff wird andernorts auch so gebraucht: http://www.alnatura.de/Alnatura%20Produkte/Produktsuche/Bio-Zwiebelschmalz-165g und http://www.kochbar.de/rezept/340640/Zwiebelschmalz.html Manche Rezepte präzisieren "Vegetarisches Z."

Comment: das geht aber dann sehr in Richtung *"Vegetarische Fleischbällchen"*, oder?

Comment: Ich sehe da eine große Ähnlichkeit zu Erdnußbutter. Nur mit dem Unterschied, daß es offenbar auch Zwiebelschmalz-Rezepte auf "echter" Schmalz-Basis gibt. Aber so ist das halt in der deutschen Küche - da wo ich jetzt wohne, muß ich beim Bäcker "Krapfen" sagen, wenn ich einen Pfannkuchen will. Die Bezeichnungen sind halt nicht immer eindeutig.